# How do I get my excel to PDF creation code to ignore the first worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have an excel file that generates order forms based on a template. When these order forms are approved they are all turned into PDFs. I would like to find a way to alter my convert to pdf code to ignore the template.

```
    Sub SavePDF()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Select

 PO = Range("C14").Value
 Supplier = Range("B4").Value


    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="Z:\Purchase Order Forms\Forms\" & PO, Quality _
    :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False _
    , OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next ws

End Sub
```

The template tab is called "PurchaseOrderForm" and the other tabs are all called *OrderNumber*&*UserName*

Cheers for any help.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Then check the name using an IF statement:

```
If ws.Name <> "PurchaseOrderForm" Then

  ' do stuff

End If
```